# Python Web Scraping?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to navigate through a website with contains NY stocks.

https://markets.ft.com/data/indices/tearsheet/constituents?s=NYA:PSE

Each page contains information of 20 stocks and there are 95 pages. The HTML code only contains information of the first 20. 
I somehow was able to navigate and go to the next page but the list of stocks that I can retrieve is not updated. 
Could someone take a look at my code and help me?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import selenium

path_to_phantomjs=r'C:\Users\h.elahi\Desktop\chromedriver' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path_to_phantomjs)
web= "https://markets.ft.com/data/indices/tearsheet/constituents?s=NYA:PSE"
driver.get(web)


element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li [@data-mod-pagination-
num='3']").click()


WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

text="/data/equities/tearsheet"

level=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "%s")]' % text)
print(level.text)
```

Comment: Did it occur to you that the site was written to *prevent* what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to load data is to load it directly from AJAX-requests:

https://markets.ft.com/data/indices/ajax/getindexconstituents?xid=566677&pagenum=2

Here you just need to set the correct `pagenum` value.

For example:

```
import requests
import json
from lxml import etree

for i in range(1, 2):
    resp = requests.get('https://markets.ft.com/data/indices/ajax/getindexconstituents?xid=566677&pagenum=%s' % i)
    // print(resp.text)
    j = json.loads(resp.text)
    h = etree.HTML(j['html'])
    print(h.xpath('//a'))
```

Output:

```
[<Element a at 0x1024692c8>, <Element a at 0x10239cac8>, <Element a at 0x10237eac8>, <Element a at 0x10239aa08>, <Element a at 0x1024667c8>, <Element a at 0x102466c48>, <Element a a
t 0x102466dc8>, <Element a at 0x102418f08>, <Element a at 0x102418cc8>, <Element a at 0x1024184c8>, <Element a at 0x1023a2bc8>, <Element a at 0x1023a2e88>, <Element a at 0x1023a2fc8
>, <Element a at 0x1023a2dc8>, <Element a at 0x1023a2108>, <Element a at 0x1023a28c8>, <Element a at 0x1023a2088>, <Element a at 0x1023a2a48>, <Element a at 0x1023a23c8>, <Element a
 at 0x1023a2788>]
```

This snippet extracts and prints all links found in responses, also using XPath you can extract any interesting data.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the "next page" it doesn't reload the html page but instead gets the content with ajax, by looking at the network packages while switching pages you can find that it retrieves the data from here:

https://markets.ft.com/data/indices/ajax/getindexconstituents?xid=566677&pagenum=2

And it looks like it's in json format.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on next page button and waiting say:`driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl())`
Use a for loop to go through the pages

Comment: Wow, getcurrenturl is exactly what was i looking for

Comment: GetCurrentUrl () returns the url in the browser then driver.get loads the source code into the variable to parse through use a variable like web or use web itself... why waste memory

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: I did actually.